# How to use npm behing an SSL Nexus registry?

Tags: npm, nexus, ca

I have installed npm on windows and tried to use it with the company Nexus. 
To do that I created the ~/.npmrc

```
registry = https://mycompany/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/
```

Then, I set up npm and tried to download a library, but npm throws an error:

```
C:\git-repos\my-npm_module>npm --loglevel info install grunt
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.15.9
npm info using node@v4.5.0
npm WARN package.json self-service-portal@1.0.0 No README data
npm info addNameTag [ 'grunt', 'latest' ]
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 09:39:42
npm http request GET https://mycompany/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/grunt
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
npm info attempt registry request try #2 at 09:39:52
npm http request GET https://mycompany/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/grunt
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

How to use npm behing an SSL Nexus registry?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my problem was to add the strict-ssl false parameter and ca to empty in .npmrc file

```
registry = https://mycompany/nexus/content/groups/npm-all/
ca=
strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: strict-ssl=false - not the best way to solve the problem ...